# Using Git Add with files that maybe don't exist

Tags: git, git-add, git-alias

On Windows, I'm trying to create an alias for Git Add to automatically select only C# related files.

My current alias is:

```
acs = add *.cs *.csproj *.sln
```

I keep getting this error: *fatal: pathspec '*.sln' did not match any files*, which is expected, since the specific folder I am in contains only the project and not the solution. (i.e. *.cs and *.csproj both exist)

I want to create an alias that would work for all C# folders.

---

Say I have 2 folders.

**Folder1** contains:

- 1.foo
- 2.foo

**Folder2** contains:

- 1.foo
- 2.bar

In Git Add, is it possible to create a line that would work for both folders, regardless of the presence of the files mentionned in the wildcards ?

I would have expected (hoped for) something like:

```
git add *.foo|*.bar
```

Is there any OR wildcard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to make `git add`'s convenience globbing ignore a pattern that doesn't match anything, but there are much more powerful ways to build command lines.

First, a handy alias:

```
git config --global alias.files 'ls-files -oc --exclude-standard'
```

then

```
git config alias.acs '!git files -z *.cs *.csproj *.sln | xargs --null git add --'
```

gets you what you want.

Comment: I needed to add --global and double quotes in order for the 2nd alias to be created, but it ended up working like a charm ! Thanks !

Comment: Actually, what I really used was `git config --global alias.acs "!git files -z \*.cs \*.csproj \*.sln | xargs --null git add --"`.

Comment: I yanked the backslashes but left the suffix selection per-repo for some reason I can't quite explain even to myself...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
acs = add --ignore-errors *.cs *.csproj *.sln
```

Comment: No, exact same result, unfortunately. This is a fatal error, while --ignore-errors only works for indexing problem (if I understand correctly)